# How to get multiple answers from the context using BertForQuestionAnswering

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

How do I get multiple answers from the text using BertForQuestionAnswering, just like for the below question there are two possible answers

1. a nice puppet
2. a software engineer

Below is the code snippet for the same:

````
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForQuestionAnswering
import torch

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad')

question, text = "Who was Jim Henson?", "Jim Henson was a nice puppet.Jim Henson was a software engineer."
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(question, text)
token_type_ids = [0 if i <= input_ids.index(102) else 1 for i in range(len(input_ids))]
start_scores, end_scores = model(torch.tensor([input_ids]), token_type_ids=torch.tensor([token_type_ids]))

all_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids)
answer = ' '.join(all_tokens[torch.argmax(start_scores) : torch.argmax(end_scores)+1])
print(answer)

'a software engineer' ``` 

Thanks in advance!!
````

Answer (score 1):

You are simply outputting the most likely answer according to BERT. If you want multiple answers, you will need to actually select multiple answers. In this case that would be the first **and** second most likely answer. To do this, create a new answer variable and select the second most likely start and answer word from the start_scores and end_scores variable. I recommend you use at torch.topk()

```
answer1_start, answer2_start = torch.topk(start_scores)
answer2_end, answer2_end = torch.topk(end_scores)

answer1 = ' '.join(all_tokens[answer1_start : answer1_end + 1])
answer2 = ' '.join(all_tokens[answer2_start : answer2_end + 1])

print(answer1, answer2)
```

Let me know how this works.